# How to create a database of english to malayalam dictionary

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am doing a project to convert english sentence to malayalam. For that ,How can I insert a english to malayalam dictionary in to mysql database? I also want to insert malayalam words to the database. I have no much idea in this topic, any help will be appreciated alot..

Comment: You should try something first and share

Comment: Depends on the format of the dictionary your trying to save to the db and the scripting language you choose for it. Post a sample data of the dictionary you have and the scripting language your using to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to think about as you get started:

- what do you want to do about alternatives? (a word in one language may have many meanings in another language)
- will you keep it just to the two languages or would you potentially like a more general design that caters for other languages in the future?
- what is the purpose of your database, is it a simple lookup or would you want to test people  or have some sort of "correctness" measure (close but not 100% equal)
- would you like to cater for transliteration of malayalam characters
- do you want to cater for word types (verbs, nouns, adjectives, etc.) of the grammars

Answers to these will influence how complex and sophisticated your solution is. At the most basic, however, you could start with a language, phrase and meaning table along the lines of:

- language table (currently only two rows, english and malayalam)
- phrase table (each phrase is in a single language, M:1 relationship to language)
- meaning table (is a M:M between phrases, so links one phrase (source) to several other phrases (targets) and vice versa, where your code should check that the language of the linked phrase is different to the language of the source phrase). has to M:1 relationships to phrase, one for source and one for target.

Fun assignment, let us know how you get on.